# error upon installation of clearscript via nuget in azure web role project

Tags: azure, nuget, clearscript

steps to reproduce:

a.run this line in PM console:

> Install-Package ClearScript.V8

b.run the application

c.receive this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8-32.DLL' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

I assume the DLLS need to be moved into a content folder in the web role, and that some configuration needs to be done to allow either the x86 or x64 DLL to be selected depending on OS

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ClearScript [ReadMe](https://clearscript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReadMe.txt). There's information there about integrating ClearScript with ASP.NET projects. The NuGet package doesn't quite work for ASP.NET.